# Ionic how to add camera plugin

Tags: plugins, ionic-framework

I am trying to add camera plugin under my ionic project.

I did as follow:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera`

```
(in app/res/xml/config.xml)
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>


(in app/AndroidManifest)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But there is no `navigator.camera` in a browser console. Did I missed something?

Comment: You can't use `navigator.camera` until the `deviceready` event has fired - just checking that's not the problem?

Comment: There should be an event after 5 seconds if device is still not ready. But my console is clear, no notifications like that.

Comment: Viewing your HTML pages in a browser won't fire the `deviceready` unless it's emulating a Cordova device? I've found it's very difficult to debug a Cordova application in a normal browser, and tend to use tools like Weinre instead. Let me know if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I added update one of page elements afteer 6 seconds if `navigator.camera` and then emulated it, but no changes appeared.

Comment: but afterall you have right. i need to wait for a deviceReady event. If you wish to add an official answer I will vote on it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem at all, glad you worked it out. Just posted an answer, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera plugin isn't available (via `navigator.camera`) until after the `deviceready` event has fired.

Unfortunately you can't test this functionality in a normal web browser as it relies on native Cordova plugins, so you'll need to test using a real device or simulator.

[cordova-plugin-camera documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)